# can't make it look all in one line when display it on html page

Tags: vue.js

vue.js
how can I make it look all in one line, next to each other?

*TEMPLATE:*

```
<div class="product">
  <button @click="removeFromCart" :disabled="!inStock"> &minus;</button> 
  <span>
    <p v-if=  "inStock == 0"> &#128148; <span :class="{isRed: inStock === 0}"> {{inStock}} </span> </p> 
    <p v-else> &hearts; {{inStock}}</p>
    <button  @click="addToCart" > + </button>
  </span>
</div>
```

Comment: The detail you have provided in not enough; Your question is vague, please try to explain your issue better.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `class="row"` for example in your `div`. Than all *buttons*, *p-tags* and so one will be shown on a row - like this:

```
<div class="row">
  <!-- YOUR CODE IN HERE -->
</div>
```

To define the width of your `b-button`, `p-tags`, etc. you can use `class="col-md-5` for example.. here is a link how you can define the width of a element in `vue.js`.

URL: https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/grids/#order-first-and-last

Hopefully this helps you out.